# iPhone UITableView bug??? - sectionIndexTitlesForTableView seems to cause it?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, navigation

I have got this super weird bug in my current project. To understand what is going on, I narrowed down everything to the simplest app, which can be downloaded here:

[download simple example here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-3163540/simple2.zip.html) (no autoreleasing of the mentioned indexes array here)

It seems like the method: sectionIndexTitlesForTableView has something to do with it as the bug does not appear when it is not implemented. Super weird thing though: When it gets stuck and you **shake the device it responds again**. If you downloaded the code above, in the app you have to press the button, scroll down go back while its still scrolling and press it again and it will definitely crash after a few times. If not just restart it and try it again. It will crash eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that this is an iOS bug. I have not filed it yet. But I will update this post as soon as I have.

Answer (score 0):

When you are popping the tableview controller are you unsetting any delegates that may be attached to it's viewController?` I have found this to be the cause of some 'interesting' effects in the past with various components of iOS

Comment: In the dealloc method I set the datasource and the delegate of the tableview to nil...

Answer (score 0):

Can you get this to happen while you're debugging the app on your device in Xcode?  If so, once it's hung click on the Pause button in Xcode.  This will break the debugger into your running process.  Then you can examine each thread in the Threads area of the debugger to see where the callstack is.  That'll show you where your code is hung.

Comment: Yes I can do that. And I have tried it. But I have no idea of what this tells me as I dont know much about what goes on behind the scenes of objective c. But I really narrowed down my code to the simplest app (even much simpler than the sample code provided above) and I still get the error. I have no clue what could possibly be wrong. If this is an apple bug, it would be a quite terrible one.

Comment: Ok, could you copy the callstack from Xcode and paste it into your question description?  That would help us help you diagnose it.

Comment: Ok. I uploaded some screenshots. Not sure what exactly we need. But should do as a starting point hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Your autoreleased "NSMutableArray *indexes" is probably being referenced and not retained by the UITableView. I would suggest trying to create the array during init of the UITaleView and release it on dealloc of the UITableView or if it needs to be dynamic, release and recreate it each time sectionIndexTitlesForTableView is called. That way you know it will stick around as long as the UITableView is trying to access the pointer returned by this method.

Comment: Hey thanks for checking the code. But that`s not it. I will upload another version where its not autoreleased. Same bug. You can try it yourself. Cheers